# How can I load a UIView from the same NIB (stems from a UITabController)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

So I have a UITabViewController from which a UIViewController (FirstViewController) is loaded (for the first tab button) and I want a button (calcbutton) to open a UIView (calculateview) from within the same NIB of that initial UIView (bedtime)

So basically I want calculateview to animate in when calcbutton is pressed and eventually dismissed with the other "close" button. I have not yet declared or created the IBAction that would dismiss the second view.

[Here's an Xcode Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24vcX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a ModalViewController, but that will require moving your other UIView ( calbulateview) to that controller.
If that is not possible, you could still do it within your own view controller.

Use [transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView%3atoView%3aduration%3aoptions%3acompletion%3a)

Here is a short sample:

```
            [UIView transitionFromView:bedtime 
                                toView:calculateview 
                              duration:1.0 
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                if (finished) {
                                    // In case you need to do something once
                                    // the animation is completed
                                }
                            }];
```

In options you could specify other types of transition animations.

Comment: Would you recommend using the ModalViewController over transitionFromView? Are there advantages?

Comment: To keep each ViewController's code simpler. Also, it is a bit simpler to dismiss the modal view when tapping close.
In the other hand, Modal View controller have less animation transition styles.
Well, both will achieve the same goal, so it's up to you to choose which one suits you better.

Comment: I went with the ModalViewController. It was just so much easier with only a simple line to present and one simple line to dismiss.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is a modal view controller.

This should explain what you need:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Comment: But doesn't this require that I set up another view controller entirely? Can I just call the UIView modally or should I just create a view controller within the same NIB, add the UIView to it and use the modalTransitionStyle method?

Comment: a modal view is just a way of presenting a view, you can present any view in that fashion with 
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

The difference between his transition to view and modal view is whether you are pushing a controller or a view. If you have a controller for your calculateview (probably should) then you can push the controller like this and it will slide the view in.